# How can I write a GEOTIFF in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, geotiff-tiff

I want to upload a jpeg or some raster image into a C# form and then on entering the latitude and longitudes I need to be able to create an GEOTIFF file of the same image.
How can this be done in C#.NET?

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) [C#/.Net bindings](http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/GdalOgrInCsharp) to do this.

Comment: i have downloaded them, i want to use it in visual studio 2010 using C#, is there any built in function?

Answer (score 2):

You can use BitMiracle's open source [LibTiff.Net](http://bitmiracle.com/libtiff/) library.

Comment: no i want to use GDAL